# Declare variable whose type is a function's return type

Tags: scala, dependent-type

I'm currently using a type alias:

```
type FooType = Int
val foo = (_: Int) * 2

def takeFooRet(x: FooType) = ...
```

however, I'd like to do something like:

```
val foo = (_: Int) * 2

def takeFooRate(x: foo.RetType) = ...
```

I'm not seeing anything in [Function1](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function1). Is it impossible?

Comment: `Function1` doesn't have an abstract type in it, so I think you would need some implicit conversion, and the implementation would be macro.

Answer (score 3):

It's not impossible, but you would need `Function1` to expose its return type as a type member. Unfortunately this is not the case, but you can wrap `Function1` into something that gives you the information you need. Here's a trivial example

```
class Function1Aux[T1, R](f: Function1[T1, R]) {
  type Out = R
}

val foo = new Function1Aux((_: Int) * 2)

def takeFooRate(x: foo.Out) = x
```

I realize it's not pretty, but it shows that it's technically possible.

Comment: Well, then you can just add `implicit def Fn1ToAux[A, B](f: Function1[A, B]): Function1Aux[A, B] = new Function1Aux[A, B](f)` and use your normal functions

Comment: @laughdelic if that would work, you could just replace `class` with `implicit class` and be done with it, but apparently accessing a type member is not enough to trigger the implicit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know input type or parametrize your 'takeFooRate' with some type

```
def takeFooRate[+Out](x: Int => Out) = ...
```

or

```
def takeFooRate[-In,+Out](x: In => Out) = ...
```

Comment: well it needs to know the type :)